# Multi touch with appcelerator titanium

Tags: titanium, multi-touch, appcelerator

I'm currently building a iPhone App which require the multitouch (here to resize an ImageView) but I didn't find any documentation / tutorials about such a feature.

Is it possible to do so?

then how?

**EDIT**
Here is a link I found, but i don't know how to use it (I mean, when I try to build this like it's said in the readme, I have errors about Timodule/h, TiUIView.h etc).
https://github.com/masuidrive/TiMultitouch

Thanks,

KiTe.

Comment: You can test multitouch in the iOS Simulator by holding down the option key.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know this feature. Is there a way to handle it in titanium? Otherwise I'll try the scrollview solution given by gerry3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, no way to do a well handled multitouch on iPhone with Titanium simply for now. Let's wait the 1.7 version. Or switch technology ^^

Comment: If you decide to do native iOS dev, check out gesture recognizers. You can even create custom ones.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do pinch to zoom stuff, try adding your ImageView to a ScrollView and setting up zooming on the ScrollView.

If you need custom stuff, you may be able to listen for the touchstart, touchmmove, and touchend events that are fired by your views.